# FFMPEG GIF without loop, without transparency

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, terminal, transparency, animated-gif

I use the following bash file in Terminal to transcode video files to high quality gifs.

```
#!/bin/sh

palette="/tmp/palette.png"

filters="fps=25,scale=576:-1.78:flags=lanczos"

ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] 
paletteuse" -y $2
```

Right now a 6 second video ends up as a 10 second gif. Which is a bit odd since the framerate matches. I guess it's due to looping.

Is it possible to add a simple filter that prevents looping.

And also a filter that prevents transparency?

Source is a prores422 file.

Comment: You can add `-loop -1` as an output option. See `ffmpeg -h muxer=gif`. What are you using to get the duration of the GIF output? Show the console output from the commands without `-v warning`.

Comment: Found out the `palettegen` [enables](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-February/168760.html) transparency by default. Gonna try out the bash with `palettegen=reserve_transparent=off` later tonight and report back.

Comment: @llogan [console output for palettegen command](https://pastebin.com/thANMdjK) and the [console output for the paletteuse command](https://pastebin.com/CP6JrTEc).

Transparency is not disabled by using `palettegen=reserve_transparent=off`.